# Problem on set questions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been working on this set problem for hours. I have no idea how to solve it. Can you solve and explain it for me? Thanks!

> $87$ students had taken English course
>   $35$ students had taken biology course
>   $76$ students had taken mathematics course

From these students,

> $18$ students who taken English courses didn't take other courses,
>   $20$ students who taken biology courses didn't take other courses, and
>   $14$ students who taken mathematics course didn't take other courses.

Besides that,

> only $11$ students had taken all three courses.

Comment: What did you try so far ? Did you try to draw 3 "potatoes" intersecting each other ?

Comment: It seems the question fell out somewhere on the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is set theory and a little bit of linear algebra ( linear equation systems ).

Do you know of Venn diagrams? Here is one Venn diagram of your problem. (I guess it could be the same as "intersecting potatoes", but not sure.)

[image]

Maybe this can help you set up equations to solve your problem. If the circle with Biology in total should be 35 and so on... then how will the x,y and w relate to the other numbers?